# Can we change truffle to use ether.js instead of web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, contract-design, remix

I have been trying to pass string arrays to my .sol function but it is not possible with Web3j. Can i Change Truffle to use ethers.js instead of Web3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No. Truffle has some dependencies on web3js v0.20 (and there's a branch with support for web3js v1.0). Ethersjs and web3js are not 100% compatible so you might have some problems making everything work.

Long answer: You can use truffle only for contract development, write contracts in solidity, deploy contracts and test those contracts, and you can use ethersjs for writting your application.

To instantiate a contract you only need the deployment address and the contract ABI. These are written by truffle inside .json files in the `build/` directory. With that you can write your backend and/or frontend without relying on truffle and you can use ethersjs or web3 v1.0 (or any other ethereum framework like web3.py).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Truffle, you can use Waffle.

Waffle is like Truffle, but it uses ethers.js.

Waffle is also simple, faster and sweeter :)

**Waffle**

Website: https://getwaffle.io

Github: https://github.com/ethworks/waffle

Documentation: https://ethereum-waffle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/